# Calculate $ \oint_\gamma \frac{\ln(1 - \overline z)}{z - w} dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I'm trying to calculate

$$ \oint_\gamma \frac{\ln(1 - \overline z)}{z - w} dz$$

where I'm taking the principal branch of the logarithm, $\gamma$ is a smooth curve in the complex plane and $w \in \mathbb C$.

If $\gamma$ is the unit circle and $|w| \leq 1$ (that is, $w$ is in the domain inscribed by $\gamma$) I believe the answer is just $0$.  I'd like to expand the result to a larger class of curves, but the conjugate in the log term is throwing me for a loop (pun!).

Can anyone solve this for a wider class of curves?

Comment: the problem is that the complex logarithm is not continuous in any closed path around the zero, so you can't use the Cauchy integral formula

Comment: @Masacroso Unless I grossly misunderstand something, the principal value/branch of the complex logarithm (which is a subset of the full complex log) is both analytic and continuous on the domain $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\inf, 0]$.  That branch cut can be sort of hidden by starting and ending the path integral along it.

Comment: yes, the principal branch of the logarithm is holomorphic in $\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$  but not in $\mathbb{C}$. Note that any closed path around the zero doesn't belong to the domain of this logarithm because any such path contains at least one negative number. You can extend the complex logarithm to the whole $\Bbb C$ but then it is not anymore holomorphic or continuous

Comment: @Masacroso - I was imagining something like the limit as the two endpoints of an open curve approached the same point from either side of the branch cut.  I believe that's basically the Cauchy principal value?  There's probably a very resonable argument to be had about if that's actually defining the integral on $\mathbb{C}$ or not, but for my purposes it's good enough.  A lot of methods (for instance the fundamental theorem of calculus for analytic functions) can work on star shaped domains.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
I'll consider the second paragraph case $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{"If}\ \gamma\ \mbox{is the unit circle and}\ w \in \gamma\ldots\mbox{"}~}}$:

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
{\ln\pars{1 - \overline{z}} \over z - w}\,\dd z
\,\right\vert_{\ \verts{w}\ <\ 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
{\ln\pars{1 - 1/z} \over z - w}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] \stackrel{z\ \mapsto\ 1/z}{=}\,\,\,&
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\,
{\ln\pars{1 - z} \over 1/z - w}\,{\dd z \over z^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over w}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\,\,\,
{\ln\pars{1 - z} \over z\pars{1/w - z}}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] &\ = \bbx{\large 0} \\ & 
\end{align}

Comment: Yep that's what I did to get 0, too, for this case.  You can expand the result to include circles of any size with a bit more work, I think, but I'm at a loss at how to expand it to non circlular curves, for instance the curve described by the polar function $r(\theta) = a + cos(5 \theta)$

Comment: From @Masacroso comment I realize I had ambiguously worded it by saying $w \in \gamma$, since it's not clear if I mean on the boundary or in the domain whos boundary is $\gamma$, so I've changed the wording in the question to just be $|w| \leq 1$

Comment: @Masacroso Got it. Thanks.